# When is a point on elliptic curve on p-adic is considered near to point at infinity?

Tags: elliptic-curves, p-adic-number-theory

In the answer for [What is p-adic logarithmic map of an elliptic curve? How to compute it?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3021935/what-is-p-adic-logarithmic-map-of-an-elliptic-curve-how-to-compute-it) @alex-j-best says:

> sage: pP,pQ # points near infinity we can take log of

pP = $((4a + 4)5^-2 + (a + 1) + (2a + 2)5 + (a + 1)5^2 + (2a + 3)5^3 + (2a + 2)5^4 + (3a + 3)5^5 + (4a + 1)5^6 + (a + 2)5^7 + (a + 1)5^8 + 4a5^9 + (3a + 4)5^10 + 3a5^11 + (a + 4)5^12 + a5^13 + (4a + 3)5^14 + (a + 2)5^15 + O(5^17) : (4a + 3)5^-3 + (4a + 2)5^-2 + (a + 2)5^-1 + (4a + 4) + 2a5 + (a + 1)5^2 + 5^3 + 5^4 + (2a + 2)5^5 + (4a + 1)5^6 + (a + 3)5^7 + 35^8 + (4a + 1)5^9 + 25^10 + (2a + 2)5^11 + (a + 1)5^12 + (3a + 3)5^13 + 2a5^14 + O(5^16) : 1 + O(5^20))$

pQ = $((a + 1)5^-2 + (4a + 4)5^-1 + (4a + 4) + a5 + (4a + 1)5^2 + (2a + 3)5^4 + (2a + 3)5^5 + (3a + 2)5^6 + (3a + 3)5^7 + (3a + 4)5^8 + 3a5^9 + (4a + 3)5^10 + (3a + 1)5^11 + (a + 4)5^12 + (3a + 4)5^13 + (3a + 3)5^14 + (4a + 2)5^15 + (a + 1)5^16 + O(5^17) : (3a + 1)5^-3 + (3a + 3)5^-2 + (3a + 2)5^-1 + (2a + 1) + 45 + (4a + 3)5^2 + (3a + 2)5^3 + (2a + 1)5^4 + (4a + 3)5^5 + (4a + 4)5^6 + (a + 3)5^7 + (3a + 3)5^9 + 35^11 + 2a5^13 + a5^14 + (4a + 2)5^15 + O(5^16) : 1 + O(5^20)))$

why are those points near to point at infinity?

Comment: As you can easily see, I hope, it's practically impossible to understand what you wrote. Being a member for almost 6 years I'd expect you'd use by now MathJax...

Comment: @DonAntonio this is the Sage's output from the answer from Alex Best just saying...

Comment: As you wish...Perhaps there is someone willing to get into that as it is.

Comment: @DonAntonio I make some edit . Is it better :) ?

Comment: I’m awfully sorry, but I don’t understand your question. What does it mean for a point to converge to infinity?

Comment: @Lubin Sorry Professor Lubin I edited my question to "point at infinity". As said I based my wording on the answer and the sage comment in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3021935/what-is-p-adic-logarithmic-map-of-an-elliptic-curve-how-to-compute-it

Comment: @Lubin I refined a bit my question. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to your question is that a point is near infinity if its ordinary $(x,y)$-coordinates are large. In the case of your specific points, here’s what I say:

It looks as if you’re using the $5$-adic metric, and it looks (granting that your post still needs editing to make its MathJax grammatical) as if your first point is $\bigl(\frac{4a+4}{5^2}+\cdots:\frac{4a+3}{5^3+\cdots}:\,1 \bigr)$. That is, the point is given in homogeneous coordinates $(x:y:z)$.

Multiplying through by $5^3$, we get an equivalent description of your point as
$\bigl(5(4a+4)+\cdots:(4a+3)+\cdots:5^3\bigr)\,.$ Now, the “point at infinity” has coordinates $(0:1:0)$, so you see, thinking $5$-adically, that your (first) point is close to infinity. Same story for the second point.

Sage did you dirt by giving you **far** too much information.

**EDIT**: Addition

You have asked why $\bigl(5(4a+4)+\cdots:(4a+3)+\cdots:5^3\bigr)$ is like $(0:1:0)$. These are homogeneous coordinates, so if we call $u$ the middle coordinate I’ve just mentioned, then you have a homogeneous  description of our point as
$$
\left(5\frac{4a+4+\cdots}u:1:\frac{5^3}u \right)\,,
$$
after dividing all three coordinates by $u$. Then the first coordinate is divisible by $5$ and the third is exactly divisible by $5^3$, since $u$ is a $5$-adic unit. Divisible by powers of $5$ means small, i.e. close to zero.

Comment: Thanks a lot Prof @Lubin!! I am still ramping up with padics so sorry for the silly question but why $\bigl(5(4a+4)+\cdots$ is equal to 0 and why $(4a+3)+\cdots$ is equal to 1 . This is probably what I am missing :S